# CSS Columns - position title into 2nd column of text flow

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have text flowing across CSS Columns - with a title section in the markup.
Without changing my markup, Is it possible to place the title section at the top of the second column, and have the rest of the text flow across the column accordingly?

Current output is:
[image]

The desired output is along the lines of:
[image]

Example of my code here:
https://jsbin.com/jadevur/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<main>
<article>
<div class="intro">
<h1>Main Title</h1>
<h2 class="secondary">Secondary Title</h2>
<h2 class="tertiary">Tertiary Title</h2>
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non risus a libero sagittis interdum ...... etc...
</p>
</article>
```

HTML and CSS are both in the jsbin above

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, and I can see why you'd want to do this. However, without changing the HTML markup, it can't be done. According to [W3 spec](http://A%20multi-column%20element%20establishes%20a%20new%20block%20formatting%20context,%20as%20per%20CSS%202.1%20section%209.4.1.):

> A multi-column element establishes a new block formatting context, as per CSS 2.1 section 9.4.1.

There is no way of moving the `.intro` DIV to the desired position within the block, and if it was outside it, it couldn't affect position of elements within it.

The `flex-box` model allows reordering, so if the markup can be changed, that would be the method to use instead of columns. Though it might be difficult without Javascript.